# Can't convert a LINQ result using GroupBy() and ToDictionary() to return Dictionary object

Tags: c#, linq, dictionary

I'm trying to refactor a code and separating parts in functions that delegate their own functionality but can't appear to do in the following part:

```
var gPings = tractorPings.GroupBy(g => new { Lat = g.Latitude, Lon = g.Longitude })
             .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(g => g));
```

Extracted the code in a separate function with resharper and it now looks like this:

```
private static Dictionary<, List<GpsPing>> GetGpsPingsDictionary(IEnumerable<GpsPing> tractorPings)
        {
            var gPings = tractorPings.GroupBy(g => new { Lat = g.Latitude, Lon = g.Longitude })
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Select(g => g));
            return gPings;
        }
```

But the function has the following error:
[image: Error Image]
Been searching for a while now but I can't seem to find an answer for this if someone can please help me that would be awesome!

Comment: I suppose you'll need to define a data type for the returned dictionary's `Key`? It is currently not set: `Dictionary<, List<GpsPing>>`

Comment: If it's an option for you to replace the anonymous type with a [named tuple](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples#tuple-field-names), you could implement your method as follows: [example fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RiBDUT)

Comment: Thank you so much Astrid, named tuple worked like a charm you're amazing!